# Forcing a white background on my Like Box

Tags: background, facebook-likebox

I am pretty uneducated with coding, but I have managed to add a like box to our page. My problem is that it is transparent and matching the background of the page. I would like the box to stay white, but cannot figure it out for the life of me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Heres the code at the top of my page:

```
<iframe tabIndex="-32768" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FTotal-Storage-Services-LLC%2F136032556510664&amp;width=400&amp;height=427&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true" frameBorder="0" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; WIDTH: 400px; HEIGHT: 200px; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none"></iframe>
```

the page is www.totalstorageservices.com

thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 9):

Just add `background-color: white;` into the `style=""` part of the iframe;

Comment: This not works for me in Chrome mobile. A solution could be create a wrapper div with `background-color: white;`